# How to stretch my (unknown number of) labels when the window is enlarged in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

## Assignement

Create an unknown number of labels with an `ItemsControl` on a resizeable window. The Labels should be on the right offSet on the `ItemsControl`.

## Problem

I have trouble finding a way for my Labels to stretch with the window when it is re-sized to a larger format while keeping their offset to each other. My binding works perfectly. The offset also works properly, but now I need the labels to stretch along when the window is re-sized while keeping their relative distance from `Canvas.Left`.

### Code

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Labels}">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <Canvas IsItemsHost="True">
                      <Canvas.Background>
                          <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                      </Canvas.Background>
                  </Canvas>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
              <Style>
                  <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=OffSet}"/>
              </Style>
          </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Label Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
```

I couldn't find a solution and tried a lot. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not quite clear exactly what you're after. If you could post a couple of images illustrating the required visual effect that would help a lot.

Comment: apparantly you need 10 reputation points to edit an image to your post... But think of it as a compass where I get a left number (e.g. 102 degrees) and right number (e.g. 169 degrees) which are both user generated and I need to put a label with the correct amount of degrees every 10 degrees.
In this case after 8 degrees the label needs to state 110, and after that 120, 130 etc.

Comment: So your `Label` controls represent degree intervals every 10 degrees?

Comment: correct, where the first offSet is the obvious variable because of the input the user can type as the left start. That I can accomplish with the above code.

Comment: So if the two user numbers were 100 and 150, giving a range of 50 degrees, would you expect to see six labels (ie. 100, 110, 120, 130, 140 and 150)?

Comment: No, it won't give 100 but it WILL give 150.

Comment: But it's more a question about re-sizing and scaling. Because when the window re-sizes larger (it can't re-size smaller) the labels need to resize with the window. I tried (horrible) constructions like putting canvas in a wrappanel or the other way around. but that won't compile.

Comment: My suggestion would be to forget the `Canvas` and calculating the label offsets in code, and use something like a `UniformGrid` instead, with its `Rows` property set to 1 and its `Columns` property set via binding. Then work out the number of labels you will need (given the two user values) and have a binding property for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, I think a better panel to use in this instance might be a `UniformGrid`. As long as you can work out in code what your degree values are going to be, you can make a collection of those that you can bind to.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Degrees}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Degrees = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => x * 10 + 100).ToArray();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        public int[] Degrees { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

As you will see when you resize the window, the individual elements resize to take up the appropriate widths.

I think this is the type of thing you're after but please comment if not and I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks Steven. I've tried your solution and it does work (although not with the precision I wanted). Since I don't have an alternative I'll stick with it for now. If I find a better solution I'll let you know :-)

Comment: There are two other approaches I can think of. The first is to write a custom panel and use that inside the `ItemsControl` instead of the `UniformGrid`. The second approach is to forego the `ItemsControl` altogether and write a custom `FrameworkElement`, overriding its `OnRender` method and effectively painting the control's appearance in code.